Why care that 1-particle states $a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}|0\rangle$ have $\langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{q}\rangle$ which are lorentz invariant?
When defining momentum eigenstates, Peskin+Schroeder (in Chapter 2) define
$$
|\mathbf{p}\rangle = \sqrt{2E_\mathbf{p}} a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}|0\rangle.
$$
The prefactor of these states $\sqrt{2E_\mathbf{p}}$ is chosen so that
$$
\langle \mathbf{p} |\mathbf{q}\rangle = 2E_\mathbf{p} (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q}).
$$
As Peskin+Schroeder explain, this choice is made because $E_\mathbf{p} \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q})$ is Lorentz invariant.
Note however there are many other books (eg. Birrell+Davies) where one instead defines the 1-particle states simply as $a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}|0\rangle$ (without the $ \sqrt{2E_\mathbf{p}} $ factor).
As far as I can tell, the latter choice is perfectly fine. In fact this choice of prefactor seems utterly irrelevant -- why would you care that $\langle \mathbf{p} |\mathbf{q}\rangle$ is Lorentz invariant? It is not clear this is really an observable and so who cares? The thing that you really do measure is the scattering amplitude, so of course I understand why you would want that to be Lorentz invariant.
Can someone explain why I should not be defining my 1-particle states as $a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}|0\rangle$, and similarly for 2- and higher...

It is a matter of convenience. Once you make every quantity in your theory be manifestly Lorentz covariant, then we don't have to worry about the Lorentz invariance of the theory. If you had anything inside that is not manifestly Lorentz covariant, then you have to always cross-check, and we don't want to keep doing this.

Both choices are unitarily equivalent (in a more or less canonical way), and as mentioned, it is a matter of convention. The book of Talagrand and the book of Dimock discuss both choices a bit, IIRC.
